# SpringBoot - Unable to Start embedded TomCat

Tags: java, spring, tomcat

I have a Spring Boot application. It runs on 2 servers. The servers have the same configuration.
One one of this it works... on the other i'm getting this exception when starting it

```
2016-04-26 08:24:17.633 ERROR [localhost-startStop-1]: Error starting Tomcat context: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException
2016-04-26 08:24:17.903 ERROR [main]: Application startup failed
org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start embedded container; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedServletContainerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.onRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:133)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:532)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:766)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.createAndRefreshContext(SpringApplication.java:361)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:307)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1191)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1180)
    at it.besmart.parkserver.StartServer.main(StartServer.java:13)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:54)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedServletContainerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.initialize(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:99)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.<init>(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:76)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.getTomcatEmbeddedServletContainer(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.java:457)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.getEmbeddedServletContainer(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.java:168)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.createEmbeddedServletContainer(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:160)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.onRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:130)
    ... 14 more
```

The stack trace continues for a lot of rows, mostly I get problems on auto wiring and injecting activities, with root cause

```
Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.HibernateException: Access to DialectResolutionInfo cannot be null when 'hibernate.dialect' not set
```

But my db.properties file is:

```
jdbc.driverClassName = com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
jdbc.url = jdbc:mysql://192.168.3.240:3306/SMARTPARK?useSSL=false
jdbc.username = parkuser
jdbc.password = xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
hibernate.show_sql = false
hibernate.format_sql = false
```

The DB is running (second server connects to it regularly..) and all privileges to users and hosts are correct

This is my pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>it.besmart</groupId>
    <artifactId>eparkserver</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>eparkserver</name>
    <description>ePark server</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.3.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <start-class>it.besmart.parkserver.StartServer</start-class>
        <!-- 
        <tomcat.version>8.0.29</tomcat.version>
         -->
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.pi4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>pi4j-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <executable>true</executable>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>server-copy</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>run</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <configuration>
                            <target>
                                <echo message="Push to server /home/pi/park/" />
                                <scp trust="yes" todir="pi:sofia2011@192.168.3.67:/home/pi/park/">
                                    <fileset dir="${basedir}/target">
                                    </fileset>
                                </scp>
                            </target>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.apache.ant</groupId>
                        <artifactId>ant-jsch</artifactId>
                        <version>1.9.6</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

All my hibernate settings are in HibernateConfiguration.class (i migrated this app from Spring MVC to Spring Boot)

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@ComponentScan({ "it.besmart" })
@PropertySource(value = { "classpath:db.properties" })
public class HibernateConfiguration {

@Autowired
private Environment environment;

@Bean
public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionfactory(){
    LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
    sessionFactory.setDataSource(dataSource());
    sessionFactory.setPackagesToScan(new String[] {"it.besmart.models"});
    sessionFactory.setHibernateProperties(hibernateProperties());
    return sessionFactory;
}

@Bean
public DataSource dataSource() {
    DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
    dataSource.setDriverClassName(environment.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.driverClassName"));
    dataSource.setUrl(environment.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.url"));
    dataSource.setUsername(environment.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.username"));
    dataSource.setPassword(environment.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.password"));
    return dataSource;
}

private Properties hibernateProperties() {
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.put("hibernate.dialect", environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.dialect"));
    properties.put("hibernate.show_sql", environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.show_sql"));
    properties.put("hibernate.format_sql", environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.format_sql"));
    return properties;        
}

@Bean
@Autowired
public HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager(SessionFactory s) {
   HibernateTransactionManager txManager = new HibernateTransactionManager();
   txManager.setSessionFactory(s);
   return txManager;
}
}
```

I don't know what is happening

Comment: Spring Boot normally configures its own DataSource and EntityManagerFactory... Why have you chosen to create your own instead of what is provided? It can be that this is interfering with your own configuration. Also is the second server even able to connect to the server, i.e. firewall rules etc.

Comment: How are you loading `db.properties`? . Spring boot standard is [`application.properties`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config-profile-specific-properties).

Comment: Edited original question, i have an HibernateConfiguration class because i refactored the app from spring MVC to Boot. But the app works on a server, and has always worked...

Comment: Have you check that in your classpath you have only on `db.properties` even in vendor dependencies ?

Comment: yes, there is only one db.properties

Comment: Could you answer to @M.Deinum questions please?

Comment: Sure, I changed DataSource to use Spring Boot default, created application.properties. Now it looks like it works, but i'm getting a new error about Bean creation, but i think i will open a new question if i cannot solve it. Thanks

Comment: Don't know if your problem is resolved. I had similar issues and found out that one of the dependencies is built with an older version of servlet-api. Springboot doesn't want you to include the servlet-api, but if the dependency is built with an older version, then you will see this error.

Answer (score 8):

Probably you can avoid this by changing your project sdk.

In my project I initially used **java-11-openjdk-amd64** as my JDK and had the same issue.

After changing JDK into **java-8-oracle** it worked.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem. Add this :

```
<dependency>
<groupId><groupId></groupId>
<artifactId><some dependency></artifactId>
<version><version></version>
<exclusions>
    <exclusion>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
</exclusions>
```

Comment: Which group? Which artifact? Which version? This is not very specific or helpful.

Answer (score 2):

On my case, the project was using `Java 8` but in my configuration it was set to `Java 11`.
Go to **project structure** -> **Project** -> **Project SDK** and change the **java version**.
I hope it helps.

Comment: my ubuntu installer default is java 11 so the tomcat failed :D, thank you

Comment: Great that I could help!

Answer (score 0):

1 ) When using Spring Boot you should not include the other Spring dependencies directly, but rely on Boot's own dependency management. When using the provided "starters" you can be sure that all needed libraries will be included in a matching version. Documentation : https://spring.io/guides/gs/spring-boot/#use-maven

2) The scheduling guide isn't a web app so you probably have some mouldy stuff in your pom.xml from the REST guide?

A "good" pom would have "spring-boot-starter-web" (for convenience) or else all the dependencies included in the starter listed individually. Just check that you have them. Also make sure you include an @EnableAutoConfiguration in your SpringApplication.  Add the classes to run in an Object array to SpringApplication's run method : SpringApplication.run(new Object[]{Application.class, ScheduledTasks.class}, args);

Enjoy :)

Comment: Sorry @Abdel but I cannot understand all you have written. I made the POM with spring boot utility, adding all the things i need (hibernate, jackson, log4j and so on) and this is what the utility gave me. I also have my start class annotated with `@SpingBootApplication` The application is just a REST repository, it starts and expose some REST services.

Answer (score 0):

Add a new file under src/main/resources with name application.properties

```
spring.datasource.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://192.168.3.240:3306/SMARTPARK?useSSL=false
spring.datasource.password=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
spring.datasource.username=parkuser
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
```

Remove `HibernateConfiguration` class & on your Main class put `@EnableTransactionManagement` annotation.

Answer (score 0):

Probably It's about the servlet.jar confliction between 'starter-web' and embedded tomcat ,use the following instead.

```
 <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
 <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
 <version>2.0.4.RELEASE</version>
```

Answer (score 0):

Suddenly i faced the same error, but for me it was the dependency below, just answering here to save others wasting time

> spring-boot-devtools

Answer (score 0):

If some one is as stupid as my self, turns out tomcat initialization uses default properties to boot, with data such of OS, kernel, etc.

By default java initializes those value automatically, however is possible to override them using `System.setProperties(newProps);`

This broke my tomcat for me....